# update a JLabel to show the current score of a snake game

Tags: java, updatepanel

[still an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Uczz.png)Hello everyone :) I am a java beginner and at the moment I am trying to program a snake game. The snake game is built on a JFrame with a GameGrid on it and some JButtons on a JPanel in the west. In the north I am trying to build a scoreboard on a JLabel where the current Score and the current "running time" should be visible.

the problem:
I sit here since 3 days and I still don't understand how to update the JLabel every second to show the new score and time. How can I update the JLabel in the background, that the compiler is still able to read the next line in the code?

[screenshotofthegame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PClA.jpg)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class menuGui {

    JFrame frame;
    JButton start;
    JButton settings;
    JButton info;
    JButton exit;

    GGSnake snake; // GameGrid wird hier definiert, damit man beim action listener unten zugreifen kann.

public static void main(String[] args) {

    menuGui gui = new menuGui();
    gui.menu(); 
    }

    public void menu() {

        //Frame
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Panel1 mit Menu JButtons
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
        frame.add(panel1,BorderLayout.WEST);

        //Spielwelt von GGSnake zu Frame hinzufügen
        snake = new GGSnake();
        frame.add(snake, BorderLayout.EAST);

        //Scoreboard
        JLabel scoreBoard = new JLabel("Score " + Snake.getScoreText());
        scoreBoard.setForeground( Color.WHITE );
        scoreBoard.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        frame.add(scoreBoard,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //Buttons
        JButton start = new JButton("Spiel starten");
        start.setBounds(120, 40, 160, 40);
        start.addActionListener(new startListener());
        panel1.add(start);

        JButton settings = new JButton("Einstellungen");
        settings.setBounds(120, 120, 160, 40);
        settings.addActionListener(new settingsListener());
        panel1.add(settings);

        JButton info = new JButton("Credits");
        info.setBounds(120, 200, 160, 40);
        info.addActionListener(new infoListener());
        panel1.add(info);

        JButton exit = new JButton("Beenden");
        exit.setBounds(120, 280, 160, 40);
        exit.addActionListener(new exitListener());
        panel1.add(exit);

        frame.setTitle("Snake");
        frame.setSize(560,423);
        frame.setBackground(Color.black);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);


        snake.requestFocusInWindow(); // --> Tastatureingabe wird direkt auf das "GameGrid" geleitet. 

        }

    //ActionListeners
    class startListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            // altes GameGrid entfernen
            frame.remove(snake);
            // neu erstellen und hinzufuegen.
            snake = new GGSnake();
            frame.add(snake, BorderLayout.EAST);

            // frame aktualisieren (weil wir etwas entfernt und hinzugefügt haben).
            frame.validate();
            frame.repaint();
            // input aus Tastatur anfordern
            snake.requestFocusInWindow();

        }
    }
    class settingsListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        }
    }
    class infoListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        }
    }
    class exitListener implements ActionListener {
        //Anwendung wird geschlossen
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}

import ch.aplu.jgamegrid.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

class Snake extends Actor {

  private ArrayList<Tail> tailList = new ArrayList<Tail>();
  private static int tailSize = 0;
  private static long startTime;

  public Snake() {

    super(true, "sprites/snakeHead.gif");
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
  }

  public void act() {

    if (gameGrid.kbhit())
    {
      switch (gameGrid.getKeyCode())
      {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
          setDirection(Location.NORTH);
          break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
          setDirection(Location.WEST);
          break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
          setDirection(Location.EAST);
          break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
          setDirection(Location.SOUTH);
          break;
        default:
          return;
      }
    }

    int lastIndex = tailList.size() - 1;
    Location lastLocation = getLocation();
    if (lastIndex > -1)
    {
      lastLocation = tailList.get(lastIndex).getLocation();
      for (int i = lastIndex; i > 0; i--)
        tailList.get(i).setLocation(tailList.get(i - 1).getLocation());
      tailList.get(0).setLocation(getLocation());
    }
    move();
    if (!isInGrid())
    {
      gameOver();
      return;
    }

    Actor a = gameGrid.getOneActorAt(getLocation(), Tail.class);
    if (a != null)
    {
      gameOver();
      return;
    }

    tryToEat(lastLocation);
  }

  private void gameOver() {

    gameGrid.removeAllActors();
    gameGrid.addActor(new Actor("sprites/gameover.png"), new Location(10, 8));
  }

  private void tryToEat(Location lastLocation) {

    Actor actor = gameGrid.getOneActorAt(getLocation(), Food.class);
    if (actor != null)
    {
      Tail newTail = new Tail();
      gameGrid.addActor(newTail, lastLocation);
      tailList.add(newTail);
      tailSize++;
      actor.removeSelf();
      gameGrid.addActor(new Food(), gameGrid.getRandomEmptyLocation());
    }
  }

  public static String getScoreText() {

      long currentTime = (new Date().getTime() - startTime) / 1000;
      return tailSize + " tail segment(s) at " + currentTime + " s";
  }
}

import ch.aplu.jgamegrid.*;

public class GGSnake extends GameGrid {
    public int startingSpeed = 150;

    public GGSnake() {
        super(20, 20, 20, false);
        this.setBgImagePath("sprites/maxresdefault.jpg");
        this.reset();
        this.doRun();
    }

    public void reset() {
        this.removeAllActors();
        this.setSimulationPeriod(this.startingSpeed);
        Snake snake = new Snake();
        this.addActor((Actor)snake, new Location(10, 10));
        this.addActor((Actor)new Food(), this.getRandomEmptyLocation());
        snake.setDirection(Location.NORTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can update the score when it changes.for the time you can use swing timer .what you are looking for is multithreading .

Comment: @Fast Snail  I search since three days and nights :) i know i need something with another Thread but I always do something wrong. Do you have a specific examle or a welldone webpage?

Comment: i found a example on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959718/dynamic-clock-in-java .

Comment: so do I have to set a new class or can i just creat a new public void with an action listener?

Comment: both are correct . .http://pastebin.com/iT3fNp0h

Comment: But my JLabel does not accept an ActionListener?

Comment: can you post a minimal example.the game logic is not important here .so we can show you an example.but with this huge code it's hard .yur jlable doesn't need to accept action listner all you want to do is update jlable inside actionperformed method.when you call timer start  it runs parallel

Comment: ah I think now i got it. So in the actionperformed method i have update my JLabel with jlabel.setText("Score " + my variable for the current score) ?

Comment: yes ................

Comment: //Score aktualisieren
 Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
                
                scoreboard.setText("Score " + Snake.getScoreText());
            }
});    I doesn't work:( scoreboard is my JLabel and Snake.getScoreText() the method to get the score

Comment: according to the error , you should start timer after ,scoreboard and snake is iniialized

Answer (score 1):

Method written below will trigger every second. You can use it to update your score in the game.
Timer is set for 1 second(1000ms) . It will trigger ActionEvent every 1 sec, so you can use it to have your periodic score update.

```
            ActionListener l1 =new ActionListener()
            {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
          scoreboard.setText("Score " + Snake.getScoreText());
        //Add here all your logic that contribute to update every second
            }
            };

            Timer t1 = new Timer(1000,l1);
            t1.start();
```

Comment: Yes i understand the idea of this code but when i add the code,  l1 cannot be resolved to a variable? That is my error now:D

Comment: @Tobias Please add 'Timer t1 = new Timer(1000,l1);
                t1.start();' after 'ActionListener l1 =new ActionListener()
                {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
                {
              scoreboard.setText("Score " + Snake.getScoreText());
            //Add here all your logic that contribute to update every second
                }
                };'

Comment: @Tobias I have modified the answer. There was a mistake on my part. Timer should be initialised after ActionListener is declared . Please review it.

Comment: i still get one error. Do I have to add that code in after the frame.add(scoreBoard) command in the menuGui?

Comment: Add it after frame.setVisible(true). What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Tobias I hope you have added all your logic in my code in actionPerformed function to update your label.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException ;   atmenuGui$1.actionPerformed(menuGui.java:77)    ;   atjavax.swingTimerfirActionPerformed(Timer.java.291)  and some more :S

Comment: and my logic is that the jLabel refreshes, with scoreboard.setText("Score " + Snake.getScoreText()); and that the methode Snake.getScoreText() have to run once...am I right

Comment: @Tobias I am looking for the cause of the error. Please give me some time

Comment: @Tobias Which line of the code is throwing Exception ? Could you please share a screeshot of the error and code ?

Comment: I added the screenshots

Comment: @Tobias At line 76 , why have you added Snake.getScoreText()? Check ur output after removing it.

Comment: yeah thats nonsense i see.. but it is still not working

Comment: Thank you very much :) i fixed it your code was right. it was a stupid fault, I added two JLabels and there was a type mistake.

Comment: @Tobias  nice :) it was good to help you. I would be gratefully obliged if you mark my comments as Helpful or my answer as Correct. Thank you