# Java: Optimizing a while(true) loop

Tags: java, swing, loops, time

I am creating a program that gets the time and displays it in a JFrame (it also updates the background to be the color #[HOUR][MIN][SEC] like on [rhysperry.co.nf](http://rhysperry.co.nf) ). My problem is the timer seams to only update every 2-4 seconds(on lower end machines). I have the code and am wondering how I would go about optimizing an already small program.

Please tolerate bad coding practices as I still don't fully understand Java.

Here is my code - Window.java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class Window {
    /**
     * Simple color changing clock based on the website the website <a href="http://rhysperry.co.nf">rhysperry.co.nf</a>
     *
     * @author Rhys Perry
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FontFormatException, InterruptedException {

        //Import font
        InputStream in = Window.class.getResourceAsStream("Lato-Hairline.ttf");
        Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, in).deriveFont(50f);

        //Initialise the Frame, Panel and label
        JFrame frame= new JFrame("Hex Clock");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setFont(font);
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 350));
        label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        //Merge Frame, Panel and "This is a test")Label. Make window visible
        panel.add(label);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(700, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        //Setup calendar
        Calendar calendar;

        //Initialise some variables to do with time management
        String formattedhour;
        String formattedmin;
        String formattedsec;

        //Main loop to get the time and update the background ad Label
        while(true) {
            //Get hours, minutes and seconds
            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            if (hour < 10) { formattedhour = "0" + hour; } else { formattedhour = hour + "";}
            int min = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            if (min < 10) { formattedmin = "0" + min; } else { formattedmin = min + "";}
            int sec = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            if (sec < 10) { formattedsec = "0" + sec; } else { formattedsec = sec + "";}

            //Format and update the necessary components
            String time = formattedhour + ":" + formattedmin + " " + formattedsec;
            label.setText(time);
            String hex = "#" + formattedhour + formattedmin + formattedsec;
            panel.setBackground(Color.decode(hex));
            panel.repaint();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need to "optimize" that while loop, you need to get rid of it. Completely. Instead use the proper tool for repeating code in a Swing GUI, a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). Please check out the tutorial link.

Comment: You would be better off getting rid of the busy loop and using a `Timer` for updating the screen instead. One example is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959718/dynamic-clock-in-java).

Comment: Dude, your code eats the CPU open the task manager and check the cpu usage while running this. that's why it's a bit late to see the actual change.

Comment: Thx, I'll check that out. **Every EXPERIENCED programmer probably hates that code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use javax.swing.Timmer instead. It executes a task repeatedly after interval of time. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

```
   ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            //...Perform a task...

        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer(10 ,taskPerformer);
    timer.start();
```

Comment: Never use 0 as the timer delay. Use a value that makes sense, that is reasonable. You might also want to improve your answer a bit, flesh it out more.

Comment: I'm sorry for my stupidity, but I can't seem to get this to work. How do i get the variables defined outside of actionPerformed() to work inside actionPerformed()?

Comment: Create global variable for class. Or the best way which I always prefer is create a public function within class and call it in actionPerformed().